# Page up, page down, up and down keys don't work on my page

Tags: javascript

I'm making a portfolio to show my projects. So when someone clicks on Project 1 in the menu, a new div (div#project1) will slide in from the left like a new page to show Project 1.

Problem

1. Page up, page down, up and down arrows don't work on this div (div#project1) automatically.
2. I need to click on the div (div#project1) first before I can scroll with the keyboard.

How can I make it automatic? Looking for javascript answers! Thank you

```js
function project() {
  document.getElementById("project1").toggleClass('show');
  document.getElementById('project1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('focus'); // or whatever...
    this.focus();
  });
}

HTMLElement.prototype.addClass = function(string) {
  if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
    string = string.split(' ');
  }
  for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (string[i] && !new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] +
        '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string[i];
    }
  }
}

HTMLElement.prototype.toggleClass = function(string) {
  if (string) {
    if (new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string +
        '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
    } else {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string;
    }
  }
}

HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(string) {
  if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
    string = string.split(' ');
  }

  for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
    this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] +
      '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
  }
}
```

```css
.project {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 100vw;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  bottom: 0;
}

.show {
  left: 0vw!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h2 onclick="project()">Project 1</h2>
</div>

<div id="project1" class="project" onclick="project()">
  <h1>Project 1</h1>
  <center>
    <img src="x.png">
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: why do you have these prototype functions when you seem OK to use the `classList` property which offers all that? Any way it seems unrelated to your question. Better reduce your code to the essence of your question.

Comment: Oh right, I missed out that. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the `focus` method outside of the inner `click` listener callback. And when you hide the project details it is probably good to remove the focus from that:

```
function project() {
    const proj = document.getElementById("project1");
    proj.classList.toggle('show');
    proj.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('focus');
        this.blur(); // Remove focus
    });
    proj.focus(); // Set the focus on the project details that just appeared.
}
```